# Is there a way to split inline data to row data?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have to work with a large table on Google Sheet containing, roughly, weights associated with a day (and other superfluous data).

It looks like this:

| Date | Weight 1 | Weight 2 | Weight 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/22 | 20 | 22 | 21 |
| 01/02/22 | 19 | 25 |  |

A date, and multiple weights associated.

Ideally, I would need an intermediate table that includes all the columns of the initial table, but with one weight per row.

Like this one for example:

| Date | Weight |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/22 | 20 |
| 01/01/22 | 22 |
| 01/01/22 | 21 |
| 01/02/22 | 19 |
| 01/02/22 | 25 |

I tried several methods to filter this table and retrieve all the weights for each date independently.

Index/match, filter, query...

I couldn't get what I needed.

Do you know if there is a formula that would allow me to obtain this second table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(if(len(B2:D)*len(A2:A),A2:A22&"|"&B2:D22,)),"|"),"Select * Where Col2 is not null"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't knew the flatten formula. It works !

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A&"​"&B2:D), "​"), "where Col2 is not null", ))
```